# PHP - Printing values of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

How will I loop the values of **'ques_title'** ? Below is the code and its output, I even tried with looping the value i.e **$i => $value** but then no output is shown.

```
foreach($allquiz as $i) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($i);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
['ques_title'] => Ques 1
['ques_image'] => kitchenaid_mixer_ele_qNhwH.png
['choice_1'] => iphone7_rosegold.png
['choice_2'] => kitchenaid_mixer_ele_qNhwH.png
['choice'] => choice_2
['choice_3'] => iphone7_rosegold.png
['choice_4'] => iphone7_rosegold.png
['question_type'] => 1
)
Array
(
['ques_title'] => Q2
['ques_image'] => 
['choice_1'] => f
['choice_2'] => s
['choice_3'] => t
['choice_4'] => f
['question_type'] => 0
)
```

var_dump($allquiz);

**OUTPUT:**

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
array(8) {
["'ques_title'"]=>
string(11) "qdea sdas d"
["'ques_image'"]=>
string(30) "kitchenaid_mixer_ele_qNhwH.png"
["'choice_1'"]=>
string(20) "iphone7_rosegold.png"
["'choice_2'"]=>
string(30) "kitchenaid_mixer_ele_qNhwH.png"
["'choice'"]=>
string(8) "choice_2"
["'choice_3'"]=>
string(20) "iphone7_rosegold.png"
["'choice_4'"]=>
string(20) "iphone7_rosegold.png"
["'question_type'"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
[1]=>
 array(7) {
 ["'ques_title'"]=>
string(10) "Q2sad asas"
["'ques_image'"]=>
string(0) ""
["'choice_1'"]=>
string(1) "f"
["'choice_2'"]=>
string(1) "s"
["'choice_3'"]=>
string(1) "t"
["'choice_4'"]=>
string(1) "f"
["'question_type'"]=>
string(1) "0"
}
}
```

I want to loop through all the variables and store them. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($allquiz as $i) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($i["'ques_title'"]);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Whats prints `var_dump($allquiz);` ?

Comment: In your array key name is **'ques_title'** with **'**, not **ques_title**

Comment: try `print_r($i["'ques_title'"]);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, but may I know why is the key name inside **'** with **'** ?

Comment: A keys name is set when you create the array. Or you can see the names of the keys in the output of var_dump().